# Swift Insert Rows from the top

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to insert rows from the top using insertRowsAtIndexPath? I am implementing with Firebase.

```
self.ref.child("mileage").queryOrderedByChild("user").queryEqualToValue(user.uid).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            self.mileageDatabase.append(snapshot)
            self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: self.mileageDatabase.count - 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

The above insert rows from the bottom, is there a way to insert from the top?

Answer (score 0):

The index path from

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: self.mileageDatabase.count - 1, inSection: 0)
```

adds the new row to the bottom of the table view, assuming that mileageDatabase represents the data source of your table view. Since you always want the new row to be inserted at the top you need to set the index path to 0. Assuming that your table view only has one section, you need to define your index path as following:

```
NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
```

You would also need to prepend your `snapshot` instead of appending it, otherwise your data source would be out of sync with your UI representation – what's displayed in the table view.